# javascript/ jquery focus issue in IE8 and before

Tags: javascript, jquery, formatting, focus

I have a small problem.

currently, I have the following function for formatting currency on the focus/blur of an input text field:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/jFxBt/)

```
    $('.number').bind({
        focus: function() {
            $(this).val('$' + $(this).val());
        },
        blur: function() {
            var defVal = $(this)[0].defaultValue; 
            var dollars = $(this).val();
            dollars = dollars.replace('$', '');
            dollars = dollars.replace(',', '');
            dollars = parseFloat(dollars).toFixed(2);
            if (!(isNaN(dollars))) {
            $(this).val(dollars);
            } else {$(this).val(defVal).removeClass('inpt_validBlur');};
        }
    });
```

This works just as desired in Firefox, Safari, and IE9, but in prior versions of IE there is an issue. in IE, when you start typing, your text comes BEFORE the dollar sign, not after.  Does anyone know the reason for this and how to get around it?

Thank you

Comment: On a side note, you define `n` but you don't use it. Also `n` and `dollars` have not been defined with `var` which you should always do.

Comment: fixed, thank you. I see you added a fiddle... is that just for demo purposes? Do you suggest I do that when I create such posts?

Comment: Always a good idea. Here is one with a class http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mwSsC/

Comment: thanks! do you see what I mean in IE8? the cursor is jumping on focus... I am almost wondering if I should push the cursor, if its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to be working for me. Not perfect, and I dont really like mixing javascript and jquery, but it works.

```
 $('.inpt').focus(function() {
        var dollars = $(this).val();
        var defVal = $(this)[0].defaultValue;
        $(this).removeClass('inpt').addClass('inpt_Focus');
        if ($(this).val() === defVal || $(this).val() === '$') {
            $(this).val('');
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('number')) {
            $(this).val('$' + $(this).val());
            var elemLen = $(this).length;
            if (document.selection) {
                var oSel = document.selection.createRange();
                oSel.moveStart('character', -elemLen);
                oSel.moveStart('character', elemLen);
                oSel.moveEnd('character', 0);
                oSel.select();
            }
        }
    });
```